# Proving convergence for series containing ln and factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show whether or not the following series ${a_n}$ converges. Based on the hint, I have tried using Bertrand's test, but I am having a hard time simplifying the absolute value of the ratio.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac{n^\alpha (\ln (n))^n}{n!}$

hint: $|\ln(\ln(n+1)) - \ln(\ln(n))| \leq$ $\frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$

When I simplify $|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$ for Bertrand's Test, I am left with $\frac{(n+1)(n^\alpha)(\ln (n))^n}{(n+1)^\alpha(\ln(n+1))^{(n+1)}}$

and of course $\frac{(n+1)^\alpha(\ln(n+1))^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)(n^\alpha)(\ln (n))^n}$ when I try the ratio test $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Outline: We use the Root Test. For that, we want to find a biggish lower bound for $\sqrt[n]{n!}$. There are several ways to do this. A good way is to estimate the logarithm of $n!$. We choose a more elementary approach. Note that 
$$(n!)^2=[1\cdot n][2\cdot (n-1)][3\cdot (n-2)]\cdots [n\cdot 1].$$

For $k=1$ to $n$, we have $k\cdot (n-k)\ge n$.  It follows that $n!\ge n^{n/2}$.

The $n$-th root of the $n$-th term of our series is therefore less than or equal to
$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^\alpha}\log n}{n/2}.$$
This approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$.